# DOMPDF - Class 'Font' not found

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm trying to add a font via Command line.

Every time I try i get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Font' not found in 
/home/scripts/public_html/MarketingPalv2/load_font.php on line 139
```

I also get a similar error when I try to use @font-face

```
Fatal error: Class 'Font' not found in 
/home/scripts/public_html/MarketingPalv2/include/font_metrics.cls.php on line 346
```

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: This post is being close voted as "lacking information", but *the error message and filename was all I needed* to find this and the solution bellow. Thx, David :)

Answer (score 8):

I figured out what it was.

I downloaded the newest version of php-font-lib but i needed a older version.

Comment: You could help others by telling us what version of php-font-lib we need to download.

Comment: versions below 3 are comptabile, eg:version 0.2.2

Answer (score 3):

I got this working for version 0.3.1 / 0.4 of pdf-font-lib (commit: b8af0ca) and DomPDF v6.1.0 (commit: c3527d9) by making a Font class that extends FontLib\Font;

```
<?php
class Font extends FontLib\Font {
    //this is a namespace fix:
}
```

And in the class where I use DomPDF:

```
require_once('lib/dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php');
require_once('lib/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/Autoloader.php');
require_once('dir/where/you/placed/the/file/Font.php');
```

Now the class Font is available in the global namespace.

I choose this approach because I'm in a bit more dynamic situation and didn't want to change/edit the original library since it is from the master branch and it is LGPL licensed.

However, note that DomPDF 0.7.0 beta, that is released on 1 May, is out of the box compatible with the latest pdf-font-lib. Check it out: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.7.0-beta

Answer (score 2):

Solved this for dompdf 0.6.1 using latest pdf-font-lib by editing load_font.php and making the header look like:

require_once "dompdf_config.inc.php";

require_once "lib/php-font-lib/classes/Autoloader.php";
use FontLib\Font;

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help someone.

In case you get this error,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Font' not found in dompdf/include/font_metrics.cls.php on line xxx
```

You have to change `dompdf/include/font_metrics.cls.php` file as below. So it will look like;

```
require_once DOMPDF_LIB_DIR . "/class.pdf.php";
require_once DOMPDF_LIB_DIR."/php-font-lib/classes/Autoloader.php"; 
use FontLib\Font;
```

You need to add the second & third lines only. First one will be already there.

Answer (score 1):

I used dompdf-master V.0.6.1, I solved it by

`require_once "../lib/php-font-lib/classes/Autoloader.php";
 use FontLib\Font;` to  `font_metrics.cls.php` when I install new font

Answer (score 1):

I got this working for version DomPDF v6.1 by adding

```
use FontLib\Font;
```

to the file font_metrics.cls.php above

```
class Font_Metrics {
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by change `dompdf/include/font_metrics.cls.php` file as bellow

```
require_once DOMPDF_LIB_DIR . "/class.pdf.php";
require_once DOMPDF_LIB_DIR."/php-font-lib/classes/Autoloader.php"; 
use FontLib\Font;
```

copy past this code on top

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here, but working with `dompdf` in 2018 still seems to experience this issue when loading Google Fonts with CSS. The specific error I see is:

```
"Uncaught Error: Class 'FontLib\Font' not found"
```

With version 0.8.2 (July 2018) I solved by loading the `php-font-lib` library before loading `dompdf` using the following:

```
// Load DOMPDF library
require_once( 'composer/phenx/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/Autoloader.php' );
require_once( 'composer/dompdf/dompdf/src/Autoloader.php' );
Dompdf\Autoloader::register();
```

You'll need to make sure your composer path is correct here, I've removed a variable from the `require_once()` calls.